# Multiple writes to same table in oracle causing high latency

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, locking

I'm pretty new to databases and have been stuck on this problem for a while. I think I just need guidance on where to start with this kind of problem.

I have a web server set up to receive data very frequently and write it to an oracle database.

The server needs to be able to receive multiple rows worth of data per user (about 30 - 100 per 10 seconds, with occasional chucks of 1000 rows when there is a backlog).

From testing the application, it looks like there is a bottleneck when trying to scale the number of users. I suspect that I am just taking the wrong approach with how I am writing the queries / table structure.

Testing with 100 - 150 users gives me a linearly increasing response time (up to 800 seconds after 20 minutes!).

My impression is that each request with a block of data has to queue and oracle processes each write one by one, is this right? Is this due to the table being locked?

The data is all being written to one table, and each 'row' is being entered with one query. So if I have 30 rows of data It needs to run 30 inserts.

What is the best things to try when trying to improve performance?

- Will having multiple tables help?
- Is there a way to write multiple lines at once and is that likely to help?

Probably a long shot but hoping someone can help / has come across a similar problem.

Thanks.

Comment: "*It needs to run 30 inserts*" - I hope you are doing those 30 inserts in a single transaction (e.g. by disabling auto-commit and only committing *once* after the 30 inserts)

Comment: What's your Oracle version?

Comment: What's your web framework, also.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I will look into disabling auto-commit, it's not something I had done / knew about. Oracle 11g Express is what I'm using, and yes all to the same table.

Comment: Rows to insert comes from file or how you get data to insert?

Comment: The rows come over HTTP in the body of the post.

Comment: Is it PHP, Rails ... ?

Comment: It's a custom one written in Java (not by me).

Comment: In this case first advise was right from a horse :) also for some variant I can advise put xml block of data to one table, and create job that will parse and make insert of data from server side, not client.

Comment: Are you using prepared statements? Failure to do so means excessive query parsing by the database, and is a very common cause of performance problems. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: Unfortunately, as with all performance problems, your problem can be caused by various different things. However, it is important to note that when you insert data into Oracle your inserts aren't necessarily queued up. There are a few simple rules when it comes to insert speed:

* Don't commit every row if you don't have to
* Don't cause hard parses because of the lack of bind variable
* Use batch inserts

You can find more information about high performance inserts at: https://blogs.oracle.com/developer/entry/series_committing_data_to_the3

Comment: Thank you all for the advice and the references, this is exactly the information i needed to start tackling this. Will update on how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

To improve efficiency/security, I suggest you use binding variables (if you dont already use them) :

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (col1, col2) VALUES (:toto, :tata);
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (col1, col2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2');
```

This works as well for SELECTs :

```
SELECT col1 
FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID=:MYID
```

More info in the doc :
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci05bnd.htm

Secondly, If you plan on inserting multiple line at once, it would be more efficient to do bulk insert : the fewer back and forth between  the server and the client, the better it is :

For exemple, if you have an array :

```
FORALL i IN 1..MyArray.COUNT
    INSERT INTO col1 VALUES MyArray(i);
```

Also, I don't think multiple tables will help (hard to say without more info), but generally, Oracle can handle it properly without needing extra tables.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it definitely helps.